# How to remove sides padding from Google Adsense 320x50 mobile ad in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

When using Twitter Bootstrap and trying to implement a 320 by 50 mobile banner ad, I ran into an issue where on mobile, the banner would have padding on the left side (could possibly be right side as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap automatically creates a 20px padding around your body. To remove this, as was done for the mobile nav bar, implement a new class in the bootstrap-responsive file:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body {        // The code that creates a padding around the body in mobile
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.google-adsense,   // Create a new class for your ad with -20 margins (The navbar
                   // is already implemented like this so just add new class name)
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```